# Filtering query with R2DBC

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I need do a filtering query with some query parameter. I need that if the query parameter is null, the condition of the query (*=* or *LIKE*, for example) is not evaluated and return me everything. I'm using [R2DBC](https://r2dbc.io/) and I don't find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Data R2dbc, besides the above raw SQL query, you can use `R2dbcOperations` to compose `Criteria` by condition freely.

The following is an example.

```java
template
    .select(Post.class)
    .matching(
         Query
            .query(where("title").like("%" + name + "%"))// extract where here you can assemble the query condition freely.
            .limit(10)
            .offset(0)
     )
    .all();
```

Additionally using `R2dbcRepository` and convention-based method, try to use a default value in the `like`(eg. set the null to empty string `""` in `like`) to save work to determine if it is a null value in sql.

Answer (score 0):

A general prepared statement which would work might be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col = ? or ? IS NULL;
```

In the event that you bind a `NULL` value to the `?` from your obfuscation layer, the `WHERE` clause would always be true, returning all records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer doing this with a "static SQL statement" (meaning you use a single SQL string for all possible bind values), then, in Oracle, it's probably [optimal to use `NVL()` to profit from an Oracle optimiser feature, as explained in this article](https://connor-mcdonald.com/2018/02/13/nvl-vs-coalesce/), irrespective of whether you're using R2DBC:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE col = nvl(:bind, col)
```

However, a query like yours is often best implemented using [dynamic SQL, such as supported by a third party library like jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/):

```java
Flux<TRecord> result =
Flux.from(ctx
        .selectFrom(T)
        .where(bind == null ? noCondition() : T.COL.eq(bind))
     );
```

You can obviously also do this yourself, directly with R2DBC and your own dynamic SQL library, or any other such library.

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.